# How to add a column from another dataframe by matching one column or another column in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to add the values from one column of a dataframe to another dataframe by matching values from one column or another.

For example:

I have 2 df's with different length and df2 does not have all the pairs listed in df1:

df1

```
         Year Territory     Pair_ID
      1  1999       BGD         1 5
      2  2000       TAR         6 2
      3  2001       JAM         3 7
      4  2002       TER         9 2
```

df2

```
         ID1 ID2 pair pair1 type detail
      1  1   5   1 5  5 1   PO   N/A
      2  2   6   2 6  6 2   SB   N/A
      3  3   7   3 7  7 3   PO   N/A
      4  4   8   4 8  8 4   SB   N/A
      5  4   3   4 3  3 4   SB   N/A
```

I want this:

```
         Year Territory     Pair_ID  type
      1  1999       BGD         1 5   PO
      2  2000       TAR         6 2   SB
      3  2001       JAM         3 7   PO
      4  2002       TER         9 2   N/A
```

I don't want to completely merge the 2 dataframes. I just want to add the "type" column from df2 to df1 by matching the "Pair" column from df1 to either the "pair" column or "pair1" column in df2. I would also like it to fill in with "N/A" for Pairs that are not found in df2.

I could not find anything that addresses this specific problem.

I've tried this:

```
    df1$type <- df2$type[match(df1$Pairs, c(df2$pair,df2$pair1))]
```

But it only matches with the "pair" column and ignores the "pair1" column.

Comment: In your second data frame `df2` you list 8 columns of data but provide only 6 column names.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen theres 6 columns of data as well. For example, in row 1, the value "1 5" goes under "pair" and the value "5 1" goes under "pair1"

Comment: In `df1`, if I understand correctly, you could use column name `Pair_ID` to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Good case for `sqldf`:

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select df1.Year
             ,df1.Territory
             ,df1.Pair_ID
             ,df2.type

         from df1

           left join df2
                  on    df1.Pair_ID = df2.pair
                     or df1.Pair_ID = df2.pair1 
       ")
```

#### Results

```
  Year Territory Pair_ID type
1 1999       BGD     1 5   PO
2 2000       TAR     6 2   SB
3 2001       JAM     3 7   PO
4 2002       TER     9 2 <NA>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
typeA <- df2$type[match(df1$Pairs, df2$pair)]
typeB <- df2$type[match(df1$Pairs, df2$pair1)]
df1$type <- ifelse(is.na(typeA), typeB, typeA)
```